# How to generate an array using a default values array and a new values array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge, default-value

I have an array  `$d_visitors = array_count_values($d_visitors);`

```
array:7 [▼
  2 => 4
  5 => 1
  8 => 2
  3 => 1
  1 => 2
  9 => 3
  0 => 2
]
```

I'm trying to loop through that array 24 times, and check if the key **matches**, and store its value.

```
$dv = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++){
    foreach ($d_visitors as $k =>$v) {
        if($i == $k ){
            $dv[$i] = $v;
        }else{
            $dv[$i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print out something like this:

```
array:24 [▼
  0 => 2
  1 => 2
  2 => 4
  3 => 1
  4 => 0
  5 => 1
  6 => 0
  7 => 0
  8 => 2
  9 => 3
  10 => 0
  11 => 0
  12 => 0
  13 => 0
  14 => 0
  15 => 0
  16 => 0
  17 => 0
  18 => 0
  19 => 0
  20 => 0
  21 => 0
  22 => 0
  23 => 0
]
```

But I kept getting this:

```
array:24 [▼
  0 => 2
  1 => 0
  2 => 0
  3 => 0
  4 => 0
  5 => 0
  6 => 0
  7 => 0
  8 => 0
  9 => 0
  10 => 0
  11 => 0
  12 => 0
  13 => 0
  14 => 0
  15 => 0
  16 => 0
  17 => 0
  18 => 0
  19 => 0
  20 => 0
  21 => 0
  22 => 0
  23 => 0
]
```

Comment: Don't need to put else part.

Comment: @Yash : By removing it, I got this `array:7 [▼
  0 => 2
  1 => 2
  2 => 4
  3 => 1
  5 => 1
  8 => 2
  9 => 3
]` My goal is to get 24 of them. :)

Comment: Look like **@u_mulder** got my point.

Comment: In the else part you still iterate over values from $d_visitors that don't match your condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$dv = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++){
    $dv[$i] = 0;
    if (isset($d_visitors[$i])) {
        $dv[$i] = $d_visitors[$i];
    }
}
```

More simplified is:

```
$dv = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++){
    $dv[$i] = isset($d_visitors[$i])? $d_visitors[$i] : 0;
}
```

The problem in your code is in line `$dv[$i] = 0;` as it sets to zero `$dv[$i]` which earlier has been set.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one `flag` variable. Your code is also correct.

Try like this:

```
$dv = [];
        $flag = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++){
            $flag = 0;
            foreach ($d_visitors as $k =>$v) {
                if($i == $k ){
                    $dv[$i] = $v;
                    $flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if($flag == 0){
                $dv[$i] = 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of asking your process is:

How can I:

1. merge a default array with another array based on keys
2. and `ksort()` the result array?

While you can achieve your desired result using a `foreach()` loop and a condition statement on each iteration, I can show you a more concise, simple approach:

This is your new array of data: `$array=[2=>4,5=>1,8=>2,3=>1,1=>2,9=>3,0=>2];`

There are two ways to set up your default data array:

```
$defaults=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; // 24 elements with 0 value
```

or more elegantly:

```
$defaults=array_fill(0,24,0);
```

Then you only need to call `array_replace()` to overwrite the default values with the new values.  This will keep the keys in ASC order.

```
var_export(array_replace($defaults,$array));
```

You can even nest the function calls and avoid adding variable names to the global scope like this:

> ```
> $d_visitors=array_replace(array_fill(0,24,0),array_count_values($d_visitors)));
> ```

Done -- merged and ksorted.

---

To show some other ways that programmers might try to combine the two arrays (fruitlessly or illogically), here is a [demonstration](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14f4f1725ecfe6236b850b33e744bc82f512017b).